# проблема с nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

Пытаюсь выполнить команду lynx 127.0.0.1, и мне выдает ошибку 403 forbidden. Посмотрел логи, оказалось, что проблема с файлом index.html(как я понял), но вообще не понимаю, что нужно сделать, чтобы все заработало.

[image: логи]

[image]

Comment: А вы уверены, что index.html это файл, а не каталог?

Comment: честно, сам до конца не понял, в первой виртуальной машине, откуда скриншот с логами, написано, что это директория, но во второй машине это файл, который изначально был пуст, но если что-то написать, то потом показывает это в ответ на команду lynx 127.0.0.1
вот команда <nano /var/www/html/index.html>

Comment: Ну вот значит удалите каталог и создайте вместо него файл, наверное?

Comment: Большое спасибо, все получилось. Даже как-то жаль, что на такой пустяк потратил один час.

Кстати, возможно, Вы знаете, как создать виртуальный сайт на порту 8090 используя nginx. Я хочу, чтобы localhost работал на двух портах одновременно. В интернете много способов пробовал ни один не помог, а ведь задача вроде несложная

Comment: `listen 8090;` да и всё, непонятно в чём проблема

Comment: стоп, а как же создать директорию для сайта и т.д.  Я тут пытался инструкцию написать можете посмотреть https://www.notion.so/4-Nginx-4060c73067464e4e92f7a0a8f56766d2?pvs=4

Comment: mkdir да и всё, тоже непонятно в чём проблема

Comment: я вот тоже не понимаю, в чем проблема, вроде проще некуда, но какие-то ошибки возникают постоянно. Сейчас еще раз попробую, может на этот раз получиться

Comment: ничего не понимаю, возникает ошибка pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_website" failed(21: is a directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Ну а зачем вы создали каталог /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_website

Comment: я создал конфигурационный файл, а потом создал символическую ссылку для этого конфигурационного файла в директории sites-enabled, чтобы Nginx мог его использовать

Comment: Ну значит вы на самом деле создали символическую ссылку не для файла

Comment: ну я создал символическую ссылку на директорию, в которой находиться файл или нужно на сам файл ссылку ?

Comment: я переделал ссылку на файл, но ничего не поменялосб

Comment: Если «ничего не поменялосб», значит на самом деле не переделали

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все получилось